# Which data structures are used in voltdb

Tags: database, data-structures, voltdb

In Voltdb, which  data structures are used to store data when we make a query? For example, with query insert into <> value(X,X,X), How the is data actually stored in the memory.

Answer (score 1):

VoltDB is built on top of HStore database where rows of tables are placed contiguously in main memory (values are stored inline but pointers are used for long column values that use a shared pool of memory) with conventional B-tree indexing.

Although VoltDB uses Java stored procedures to run transactions, the actual tables and views are stored off the heap and are managed by the execution engine that's written in C/C++.