# Data and Index Storage in Voltdb

Tags: database, database-design, voltdb

Sorry for beginner question, but I was wondering how is data and indexes stored in voltdb? I've read a lot of documentation and papers from voltdb about how tables are partitioned and replicated and stored at the high level, but how does VoltDB handle the storage efficiently in code/backend and how is it stored in the memory?

I've read [Which data structures are used in voltdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38288266/which-data-structures-are-used-in-voltdb) but was wondering if some one can point me in the direction of where this is handled in the voltdb codebase? Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work at VoltDB. The data is stored in main memory (but not on the java heap. It is in data structures that are allocated and used independently by the C++ execution engines. The relevant code is in the [src/ee](https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb/tree/master/src/ee) subdirectory.